# Assigning 0 to character in java

Tags: java, types, char

```
    ch2 = 'E';
    ch1 = 0;
    System.out.print("the value of the ch1 and ch2 is:");
    System.out.println(ch1 + " " + ch2 + " ends");
```

for any value other than 0 assigned to ch1 both the lines are printed
but if ch1 = 0, then the second print statement does not execute.

Comment: http://ideone.com/7HNoeI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `int` `0` is equivalent to an ascii [`NUL`](http://ascii.cl/) (which happens to be a `String` terminating character in many languages, but Java is not one of them). The problem (which is also reproducible in Eclipse) lies with the console.

```
char ch1 = '\0';
System.out.printf("the value of the char is: %c ends%n", ch1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning 0 to char, it should be in single quotes. Try this:

```
ch2 = 'E';
ch1 = '0';
System.out.print("the value of the ch1 and ch2 is:");
System.out.println(ch1 + " " + ch2 + " ends");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: u can initialize the char with any value of int in the range of UNICODE!